# Creating a React/Express.js application and moving away from localhost (deploying) relative paths for the server

Tags: reactjs, express, path

I have a React app, which is currently on localhost, port 3000. The server side is being handled by a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) application, which is currently listening on localhost, port 3001.

When I run `npm start`, I concurrently start the two.
I realized in the useEffect code below that I cannot relatively set the path of my Express.js application (called with axious, because while I am on the React application (localhost, port 3000), my Express application is running on port 3001. How can I implement this as a relative path, as looking forward, when I need to deploy this application, I believe this will be a situation I will run into problems?

```html
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log("this is our use effect function")
        //we can make our async function here
        //we can call the user favourites in the db to populate our recipes
        //we can also call the db to populate the items in this users fridge.

        //we store our token in the local storage.
        async function getUser(){
            let res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users/testuser")
            console.log(res.data)
        }
        getUser()

    },[])
```

Comment: In case you are planing to host your backend and serve React frontend on the backend
see: https://youtu.be/UXjMo25Nnvc?si=WiROpxXUR9qZF49j see from prepare the deployment part

Comment: What is "axious"? Do you mean [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)? It is consistent with a (true) typo.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the help of Axios configuration defaults. You don't need to specify the full URL instead you can just specify the particular end point that needs to serve you the response. For deployment, you need to host your backend Node.js application in a separate server. (I suggest using Render.) And React app in a separate server.

After deployment you will get a URL to access the server (which will be the URL of your backend)

```
//axiosConfig.js

import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3001'; // You can replace this with your backend URL

export default axios;
```

You can also add common headers and can handle response by the use of `axios-interceptors`. Refer [axiosDocs](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults).

```
import axios from "./axiosConfig.js"; // Path to your axiosConfig file

useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser(){
      let res = await axios.get("/users/testuser", {}); // You can hit the particular end point that you need
      console.log(res.data);
    }
    getUser();
},[])
```

The React app can be hosted in [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

Remember, wherever you use Axios you need to import Axios from the *axiosConfig.js* file.